# Background color of list item not changing in mobile version

Tags: bootstrap-4

Working on Bootstrap framework, I am overriding my base CSS by defining below rule for my Navbar Dropdown list items.

The rule works fine in large and medium breakpoints but when browser width reaches mobile width, I don't get this red background and white text effect on my dropdown list items.

Any idea what should be done to get it to work properly?

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
        background-color: #aa0000;
        background-image: none;
        color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Post the HTML that belongs to that part as well.

Comment: On the mobile view (once the browser is small enough) see what `@media` query is active in the styles and override that. _Side Note: overriding bootstrap classes is not a good practice, instead define your own class and add it to the class list of the tag._

Comment: Hi Ali, Thanks for your response, I value your advice. I am just new to BS.Just want to know if it is OK to make a copy of original Bootstrap.css and override required changes there? Or do you think for each unique requirement, I should create my own classes?